# Can't install SSMS and getting error The type initializer for 'PerTypeValues`1' threw an exception

Tags: asp.net-core, ssms

I am learning ASP.NET core by myself and need to install Microsoft SSMS according to the text book.

The installation failed, stopped here and showed below error:

VSIX Installer: The type initializer for 'PerTypeValues`1' threw an exception.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFCLX.png)

I have tried a couple of times reinstalling SSMS, but still can't work out the problem.

Can anyone help with that?

Thanks,
Phil

I tried a couple of times reinstalling SSMS, but still encounter with this error. The installation stops here.

Comment: Check the `InnerException` property of the `TypeInitializationException;` it is likely to contain information about the underlying problem, and exactly where it occurred. You can find it in VSIX installer logs.